# Bootstrap navbar is not working with symfony 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am a newbie to symfony 2, so i used the traditionnal way of including bootstrap css and js files, and i faced the problem that the navbar is not working in my twig view, the code is working on a normal php web site. So here is my code

```
{%block header%}
{{ parent() }}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navbar-collapse"> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ciné-tickets</a> 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><h1>test</h1></li>
                    <li><a href = "index.php">Accueil</a></li> 
                    <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href = "" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories 
                                <i class="caret"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-inverse dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "marocain.php">Marocain</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "americain.php">Americain</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "egyptien.php">Egyptien</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "indian.php">Indian</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                    <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li> 
                    <li><a href = "connexion.php">se connecter || s'inscrire</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  <!--fin collapse navbar-collapser-->
        </div> <!--fin container-->
    </div> <!--fin navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top-->

    {%endblock%}
```

nothing show up even the :

```
    <h1> TEST </h1>
```

Thank you

Comment: if nothing shown - check php error log

Comment: the problem is in the collapse class when i remove it the list show up , and i dont know why ?

Answer (score 1):

to dump assets in to web folder you will need to run few commands in the command promt from your working derectory when working in symfony

```
php ./app/console assets:install ./web --env=prod
php ./app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

for further guidance you check the documentation : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command

Comment: thsi is not the problem the assets are working the probleme i have is with bootstrap css

Comment: How did you include the header ? Your code works perfectly fine if I paste it, so I guess it might come from the include.